# How to delete Project from Google Developers Console

Tags: google-developers-console, google-developer-tools, google-api-console

Seems like Google services are increasingly harder to manage.
Now i want to delete a project ID that was previously created in another test account.

Assuming that I could recreate it in another account. The main reason for this is that the Google+ app is connected/created in this test account and the email address will be shown when someone is confronted with the login credentials.

Google says that this is possible (https://developers.google.com/console/help/):

> **Deleting a project**
>
> Deleting a project from the Console releases all
>   resources used within the project itself.  Please note that in order
>   to delete a project, you must first disable billing on the project. 
>   Additionally, please note that the time it takes to delete a project
>   may vary based on the  number or kind of services in use within the
>   project.

When I go to billing, it shows that no billing profile has been set up.

Comment: If some one looking for delete project from GCM look out this ans  
http://stackoverflow.com/a/16624121/1601476

Comment: I frequently use this thing and routinely have to google how to do stuff in it

Answer (score 151):

The delete button is right there where the [help page](https://cloud.google.com/resource-manager/docs/creating-managing-projects#shutting_down_projects) says it is.

> To shut down a project using the Cloud Platform Console:
>
> - Open the **[Settings page](https://console.cloud.google.com/iam-admin/settings?_ga=2.60913644.-1559891757.1548749032)** in the Google Cloud Platform Console.
> - Click ***Select a project***.
> - Select a project you wish to delete, and click
>     ***Open***.
> - Click ***Shut down***.
> - Enter the Project ID and click ***Shut down***.

Please note that there is a 7-day grace period before the project is actually purged from the system. Which means you won't be able to immediately create another project with the same name.

Comment: Mi projects are still "shut down and pending deletion" after 10 days...

Comment: It needs 30-day period now to be completely removed

Comment: you need images of the buttons

Comment: @koceeng It is different from google play console project, right?

Comment: any way to expedite this now 30 day grace period? Trying to overcome "Fingerprint is already in use" issue on an oath client id i had deleted :/

Answer (score 33):

Simply go to https://console.developers.google.com/iam-admin/projects  you must be signed in of course. There you will see the all your projects google console projects so just select the project you want to delete, and click `delete project` option which is shown at the top of the table. I have provided the screenshot[image: here]

Comment: To other Googlers: this is outdated now.

Comment: The link works as of March 7th 2019. The interface doesn't look the same but you can access the 'delete' function by clicking three vertical dots on the extreme right of each project.

Comment: I used https://console.cloud.google.com/cloud-resource-manager

Answer (score 25):

Go to [**Google Cloud Console**](https://console.cloud.google.com/), select the project then [**IAM and Admin**](https://console.cloud.google.com/iam-admin/settings/) and [**Settings**](https://console.cloud.google.com/iam-admin/settings/)

[image]

now **SHUT DOWN**

[image]

Then you have to wait for the project deletion.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Feb 2019 checking in here. This is the appropriate way to do it.

Comment: Jan 2021 - This is the way

Answer (score 18):

1. Open https://console.cloud.google.com/cloud-resource-manager
2. Select the projects you want to remove
3. Click 'Remove'

Answer (score 8):

As of this writing, it was necessary to:

1. Select 'Manage all projects' from the dropdown list at the top of the Console page
2. Click the delete button (trashcan icon) for the specific project on the project listing page

Comment: Currently, In newer console this is how you delete it.

Comment: Well, I've deleted and still can't use my SHA1 key

Comment: This puts projects into a pending deletion list. Why can't it just be deleted there and then if there are not billing settings for this project. All I have is a Android Maps api key.  Hello 21st century.

Answer (score 5):

1. Click "Utilities and more" near the upper right corner of the screen after choosing your project [image: three-dotted icon]
2. Choose "Project settings" from the drop down of the "Utilities and more" icon.

Now you may see trash icon and DELETE PROJECT button.

Answer (score 1):

1. Go to the [developers console](https://console.developers.google.com/) and pick the application from the 
   dropdown
2. Select the utilities icon (see image below) and click 
   project settings
3. Click on the the Delete Project link
4. Enter the project ID and click Shutdown, project will be deleted in 7 days

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I found when I accessed here https://console.cloud.google.com/home/dashboard

Then I got redirected to my active project, which was something like 
https://console.cloud.google.com/home/dashboard?project={THE_ID_OF_YOUR_PROJECT}

Then right bellow the project info, there was this Manage Options (note: I'm using Portuguese language here "Gerenciar as configurações do projeto" means "Manage project settings")

[image]

Then, finally, the delete option ("Excluir Projeto" means Delete Project)

[image]

Yep, it was hard

Answer (score 0):

You can try delete project via Google Cloud Platform
https://console.cloud.google.com/iam-admin/projects
[image: delete project from google cloud platform]

Select required project and click DELETE PROJECT.
The project will be completely deleted after 7 days

Answer (score 0):

For me only way to delete project was switch language to English (UK) - from Polish and then button "DELETE" worked. 
If anyone have problem with not working or missing options in Google Cloud Platform I suggest switching to english after that everything works like charm...